# Unable to withdraw/unwrap my ETH from the WETH contract

Tags: solidity

I have deposited to the WETH contract and I have received the WETH in my contract. However, When I try to withdraw from the contract I keep getting an execution reverted.

```
interface IWETH9 {

    function deposit() external payable ;
    function withdraw(uint wad) external payable;
    function totalSupply() external returns (uint);  
    function approve(address guy, uint wad) external returns (bool);

}
      function stake() external payable {
    contractBalance=IERC20(WETH).balanceOf(address(this));
 

    uint256 amt = 1 * 1e18;

    IWETH9(WETH).deposit{value: address(this).balance}();

    balances[address(this)] = contractBalance;

    contractBalance=IERC20(WETH).balanceOf(address(this));

  }
  function getValue() external payable {
    // update the user's balance
    contractBalance=IERC20(WETH).balanceOf(address(this));
    uint amt = 1 * 1e18;

    bool torf = IWETH9(WETH).approve(address(this), amt);
    
    IWETH9(WETH).withdraw(amt);

    balances[address(this)] = contractBalance;

  }
```

I saw in another post that you have to have your function set as payable and I already have done that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't implement the receive and fallback functions so it technically wasn't payable. Here is the fix:

```js
receive() external payable {}

fallback() external payable {}
```

Cheers! Hope this doesn't cost you a day as it did for me.

Comment: thank you very much mate!

Answer (score -1):

Your withdraw() function has to be set to payable as well otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Withdraw is already in the interface as payable and the function calling withdraw is also payable.

Comment: The `withdraw` function doesn't need to be payable. The modifier `payable` should be used only when a function receives ether, eg when it uses `msg.value`. In this case `withdraw` doesn't receive ether it sends the ether.